# shell implementation of error string/file creation verification

Tags: bash

I have a script that written in sh/bash and run on daily basis and check SCSI/FC multipathing for all OS's. If there is an error that script generate special "Error" string and send it to syslog where our monitoring program pick it up and generate incident record for operator. I need to implement to the script the ability to generate this special "Error" to syslog not every day that error exist, but once a week. So, I need to implement that type of logic :
Day 1: Error exist - generate special "Error" string and send it to syslog and for example create temporary file with creation date
Day 2: Error exist - check temporary file creation date and if the date less then 7 days, don't generate special "Error" string and do not send it to syslog.
......
Day 8: Error exist - check temporary file creation date and if the date more then 7 days, generate special "Error" string to syslog.

What is the best way to implement this type of internal verification?

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind for me is this:

check for the error condition

do `find "error_file_dir" -mtime 7 -name "error_file"` and check the error code to see if the file was found  **edit: check number of lines returned instead of the error code**

if the file was not found, log the error and then write the error to error_file_dir/error_file (overwriting the file if its there)

The key here is the mtime argument to find. It will ensure that the file will only be returned if it has been modified in the last 7 days, in which case you don't log the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem here that the "find" exit status always success (0).

Comment: yes apparently it returns 0 even if not found. Instead, just pipe to wc -l and see if you get > 0